# Side Nav Bar not showing in mobile?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, mobile

So I'm still new to the whole css and div thing, pardon my bad coding. :/ Anyways, I have finished a site but oddly the side navbar does not appear on mobile browsers such as Chrome and the default android one. Any ideas as to why? All help is appreciated.

http://escobarboxing.com/

Also, I've tested it on my Desktop via Chrome, FF, and Opera and it appears to be working fine but another user using Chrome said he did not see it?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's because of this: #menu{position: absolute;}

Because the position is absolute, and the main content is centered, when you get to a small screen size, the menu goes behind the content. You can experiment with this just by resizing your screen really narrow.

For a quick fix, remove the position: absolute, which will fix your problem, but here's what I recommend:

Remove position absolute and relative from #menu and #container. Remove Margin right and left: auto from #container, then float #container left (float:left;). Finally, apply the auto left and right margins to #site (you'll need to specify a width first, looks like 920px should work). The #menu will stay next to the #container, and both will be centered with regards to the page.

For good measure, I'd add a 100% height and width div (#wrapper) above site.

Also, side note, if you put "position: absolute;" on anything, it's removed from the 'flow' of elements, so margins won't affect it. Here's a great article that helped me figure out position: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Welcome to CSS! It's fun, and sometimes aggravating. I hope you enjoy.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now the nav bar appears at the top instead of the side. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm. Is your page down? Sorry it didn't work quite right. If your site goes back up, I'll see what's up with it. My guess is that the #site width was too narrow, but will have to see.

Answer (score 0):

Try using %'s instead of fixed widths.  What's happening is on smaller screens the menu is covered by your content block because the block is to big for the screen.  To see what I mean open the site with your smartphone then adjust the size of your container down.  You will see your menu appear when you refresh.  I have firefox on this laptop and the menu doesn't show for me either.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding the menu div to container and remove position absolute.I see too many divs so try using less divs. why do you need that cssmenu div?

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
    <div id="cssmenu">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="insta">
    </div>
      rest of content
    </div> end container

                .insta {
                color: #333333;
                width: 100%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
                -moz-border-radius: 7px;
                border-radius: 7px;
                -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000;
                box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 #000;
                background: #EDEDED;
                float:right;
                width:770px;
                }
                #container {
                overflow: auto;
                height: auto;
                width:920px;
                                    margin:0 auto;
                }
            #menu {
            float: left;
            margin-top: 25px;
            }
```

Hope this answer helps.